# Difference between END transaction and COMMIT transaction

Tags: sql, sql-server, relational-database

I am trying to simulate a database recovery subsystem using java. However, I have the following questions.

Whenever begin transaction is issued, is it always necessary that there should be an end transaction? (Like the below example)

```
b1    --- Begin txn 1
r1(X) --- Read item X using txn 1
e1    --- End txn 1
```

As per the above example, I am not issuing a Commit transaction statement. So, will my transaction succeed or fail? If the above example, is as below,

```
b1    --- Begin txn 1
r1(X) --- Read item X using txn 1
c1    --- commit txn 1
```

what is the difference between end and commit?

Please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: SQL Server (T-SQL) hasn't command `END TRANSACTION`.

Comment: Tags belong in the tags area, not in question titles.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Either you ROLLBACK a Transaction Or COMMIT a Transaction.I hope you are not confusing  it with BEGIN and END block which is not a transaction and nothing to do with Transaction at All.

I believe in most databases .... still it ends with a ROLL BACK or COMMIT.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually in the database subsystem that am implementing, whenever I encounter END I have to write the changes in the log file for that transaction. After I encounter COMMIT, the actual changes should be written to the disk block.

Answer (score 3):

`BEGIN/END` delimits a block of code, without controlling a transaction. If not already inside a transaction, each statement will execute in an autonomous transaction. Typically `BEGIN/END` is used with branching/looping instructions (`IF/WHILE`).

`BEGIN TRANSACTION / COMMIT TRANSACTION` denotes the beginning of a transaction: each statement inside this block is executed in the same transaction and cannot be committed or rolled back individually.

Answer (score 2):

For SQL transactions coming from inside a program like that, an END statement simply closes the transaction. Meaning that the transaction is finished and nothing more should be taking place.  The COMMIT statement actually tells the database that you want the transaction changes to be PERMANENT.

If you are in "autocommit" mode, the COMMIT statement is not needed as every query/statement should be committed.

More information about COMMIT can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258243(v=sql.80).aspx).

If you are using ODBC for your database connection, information on transaction management can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131281.aspx).

Also this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2730341/sql-server-begin-end-vs-begin-trans-commit-rollback) has been asked before.

Comment: I am trying to simulate a database recovery sub system. So, the user transactions are given as begin, read, write, end, commit, abort. I have to write an algorithm for each of these user transactions. I was not sure on what to write as an algorithm for "end". I feel there is no use for an "end" issued by user, since the user is issuing "commit" or "abort". So, I wanted to know if "end" is really needed.

Answer (score 1):

The exact command names to begin and end a transaction depend on the specific database you use (unfortunately).

For example:

In [SQLite](http://sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html), you use BEGIN / BEGIN TRANSACTION to begin, and END / END TRANSACTION / COMMIT / COMMIT TRANSACTION to end a transaction.

In [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html), you use START TRANSACTION / BEGIN / BEGIN WORK and COMMIT / COMMIT WORK for the same.

Answer (score 0):

'End' is used to end the procedure/function. It is important for the statement to be executed. 
'Commit' is being used to permanently save all changes in the transaction.
For example, you have created or deleted a table using SQL Statement, you will need to commit the changes.

Read here more about the Commit Statement.
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_4010.htm

Comment: You are mistaken. Transactions are not *ended*, they are either committed or rolled back, [even in Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10713/transact.htm#autoId7 "Overview of Transaction Control (Oracle)") (which also isn't the platform the question seems to be targeting).

Comment: oh, my bad, what I mean is the process. Sorry and thanks for that.

Answer (score -1):

Please refer to this [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2730341/sql-server-begin-end-vs-begin-trans-commit-rollback) for details

> QUOTE: 
>   BEGIN TRANS and END TRANS begin and end a transaction. They DO NOT specify a new block of code; they only mark the transaction boundaries.