# Use T-SQL Transaction for batch of delete statements?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, transactions, sql-server-2016

I have a stored procedure that deletes records from multiple tables.
I wish for either all of the delete statements to complete successfully, or none. The actual purpose here is to wipe all data related to a particular user.

Note that none of this data is related in any way to any other data. E.g. a user's data is not referenced in any way by another users data. However it is possible to have concurrent client sources accessing one user's data simultaneously. I don't know if this is relevant

So I've wrapped it in `BEGIN TRANSACTION ... COMMIT TRANSACTION`

like so:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spDeleteData]
    @MyID AS INT
AS
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
        DELETE FROM [Table1] WHERE myId = @MyID;
        DELETE FROM [Table2] WHERE myId = @MyID;
        ....
    COMMIT TRANSACTION
RETURN 0
```

My question here is **what are the implications of wrapping multiple DELETE calls in a transaction?** Will it create possible deadlock scenarios, or hurt performance in some way?

From what I am reading, using `TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL` only applies to read operations, is this true?

Comment: Not sure what `END TRANSACTION` is. [TSQL has either `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK` for transactions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14806566/4416750).

Comment: You would probably want to wrap this in a try/catch. Otherwise it isn't doing anything but locking your tables for a little bit longer. There is a slight overhead for transactions but it is pretty minor unless the transactions are huge.

Comment: @LewsTherin yes that is typo. it is fixed

Comment: @SeanLange how does that give me atomicity ? For example if the third statement fails and error is caught, the first two statements would have already executed, right? I would still need a transaction

Comment: Yes, a transaction is the appropriate tool for guaranteeing atomicity of a batch of statements, provided you also use `SET XACT_ABORT ON`. No, it does not apply only to read operations, it applies to everything. Yes, you can use a transaction and still avoid locking issues, in many ways -- have the readers use snapshot isolation, apply table hints -- but since a `DELETE` ultimately always has to take exclusive locks to do its work, a transaction isn't likely to impact locking a great deal in this case.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting you stop using a transaction. I was suggesting that you should add a try/catch or as already suggested SET XACT_ABORT ON.

Comment: @SeanLange ok that makes sense

Comment: @JeroenMostert You're comment is the most comprehensive answer so far, why don't you post it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are guaranteeing is that either all the rows that match the conditions in both tables are successfully deleted or none of the rows are deleted (i.e. if there is a problem the deletes are rolled back.) There are more locks and they are kept for a longer period but if it fails you don't have to manually recreate the rows the deletes are undone for you automatically. You probably want to add the statement:

```
 set xact_abort on
```

at the beginning of the transaction and to wrap the whole thing in  a begin try/begin catch statement.

Please see  sommarskog.se/error-handling-I.html#XACT_ABORT for an execellent discussion on this statement and on error handling for TSQL.

Comment: Yeah I'm aware of the atomic behavior of a transaction, the question here is what considerations are there to using a transaction. From your answer it sounds like you are saying that there are extra locks, so there is possibly a little more overhead?

Comment: Yes there is more overhead. So the whole thing should be in a transaction if you need to rollback as a whole.

Comment: Going down to nolock is probably ignored in post 2008 SQL Server and is a very bad idea. Please see this article by Aron Bertrand:https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3172/avoid-using-nolock-on-sql-server-update-and-delete-statements/

Comment: Ok but behaviorally it should be the same right? (using transaction) Because the delete operation already acquires a lock on the table

Comment: No because if its not in a transaction (you have two deletes one following the other) as soon as the first one finishes all the locks on the first table are released.

Comment: "There are more locks and they are kept for a longer period" is not necessarily true. Specifically, even within a transaction, locks are only held for as long as necessary. A sequence of simple `DELETE` statements in a transaction should take exactly as many locks as outside, and moreover, most of them will also be released at the same time they would be outside a transaction, with the obvious exception of the schema locks on the tables.

Comment: When I tried Begin transaction delete from Table 1 where ...; delete from table2 ... without a commit and in another window tried selecting from table 1 it hung. So there are locks on table 1 being kept.

Comment: Yes, of course. Otherwise the modifications would be visible to other sessions before the transaction is committed. So forget I said that, it's not true. (At least the part about lock duration -- the *number* of locks should still not increase just because things happen in a transaction.)

Comment: if you just do delete..;delete. As soon as the first delete is done all the locks from the first delete are immediately released. If you wrap the two statements in a transaction the locks from the first statement are not released until the second delete commits or are rolled back. So the number of locks are the same but the locks are kept around longer.